How important was the US steel industry to the allies during World War II?
The United States steel plants were humming at the beginning of the second world war, due to a growing auto industry, and a decent economy as the U.S. raced out of the Great Depression.
With that being said, how much did America's strong steel industry contribute to the Allied war effort during the Second World War, in terms of raw materials for tanks, vehicles, ammunition, airplanes, warships, land lease supplies, and other logistics?
Looking for statistics and economical data.
Research Materials that I studied:

Wikipedia: History of the iron and steel industry in the United States
Wikipedia: Military Production in WW II


Are you after numbers or something else?

For the record, the US was ‘racing’ out of the Great Depression because of war production.

A huge subject upon which much has been written and which would require considerable mining to even produce the barest meaningful statistical data.  Without buying some obscure and expensive tomes, as a small sample of availability, may I suggest:
Report on Possible Steel Expansion Program as Requested by the President – September 24, 1941; Office of Production Management
Status of Steel Expansion Program - 10,000,000 Ton Increase in Capacity (AUTHORIZED SEPTEMBER 30, 1941); June 30, 1942
 Production in 1942 – War Production Board
 Production in 1944 – War Production Board
Industrial mobilization in the U.S.S.R. - Study of experience in industrial mobilization in World War II; Army Industrial College; Industrial College of the Armed Forces
Study of experience in industrial mobilization in World War II: organization for production control in World War II. A study of the follow-up and expediting function of the War Department 1939-1945; Army Industrial College (in 3 parts)
United States Army in World War II, statistics - Statistics and analysis of procurement during World War II, acquisition  and distribution of resources.
International aid statistics, World War II; a summary of War Department lend lease activities reported through 31 December 1945
Comparison of the economic mobilization in World War II of the United Kingdom, Germany, and Union of Soviet Socialist Republics with that of the United States
War Industrial Facilities Authorized July 1940 – August 1945; Civilian Production Administration
Official Munitions Production of the United States 1940-1945; War Production Board
Report of Steel Division on Steel Expansion for War; War Production Board
Report to Congress on Disposal of Government Iron and Steel Plants and Facilities; Surplus Properties Administration, October 1945
More judicious googling could probably produce other gems.

For the UK at least, not insubstantial:

the available wartime steel supply was boosted by a dramatic
increase in net steel imports. In the interwar period, the UK was
typically a net exporter of steel but in each year between 1940
and 1945 it was a net importer, averaging two million tons per
year (or 13.4 per cent of domestic steel production). This was
achieved by both boosting imports and virtually ceasing exports.
Imports increased from 1.3 million tons in 1939 to a peak of 3.05
million tons in 1941 and the main factor was undoubtedly American aid (for example, in 1942, 94 per cent of all steel imports came
from the USA). (source)


And then all the things made of steel that were shipped…
